# Match regexp at the end of the string with AWK

Tags: awk, pattern-matching, match

I am trying to match two different Regexp to long strings with awk, removing the part of the string that matches in a 35 characters window.
The problem is that the same bunch of code works when I am looking for the first (which matches at the beginnng) whereas fails to match with the second one (end of string). 
Input:

```
Regexp1(1)(2)(3)(4)(5)xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx(20)(21)(22)(23)Regexp2
```

Desired output

```
(1)(2)(3)(4)(5)xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx(20)(21)(22)(23)
```

So far I used this code that extracts correctly Regexp1, but, unfortunately, is not able to extract also Regexp2 since indexed of RSTART and RLENGTH for Regexp2 are incorrect.
Code for extracting Regexp1 (correct output):

```
awk -v F="Regexp1" '{if (match(substr($1,1,35),F)) print   substr($1,RSTART,RLENGTH)}' file
```

Code for extracting Regexp2 (wrong output)

```
awk -v F="Regexp2" '{if (match(substr($1,length($1)-35,35),F)) print substr($1,RSTART,RLENGTH)}' file
```

Despite the indexes for Regexp1 are correct, for Regexp2 indexes are wrond (RSTART=13). I cannot figure out how to extract the second Regexp.

Comment: I think you want `length($1)-35,36` Also you have to extract the `substr` from the `substr($1,length(..),...)` as you are matching it, not `$1`. Your "Desired output" is most misleading - your first code just prints `Regexp1` for the example input. What should the second code snipped print? Do you want to match some patterns on the beginning and the end? or extract the data between two patterns `Regexp1` and `Regexp2`? Do `Regexp[12]` stand for a regular expression, are are these plain strings?

Comment: I'd like to extract both the strings matching Regexp1 and Regexp2. I want to do it separately for Regexp1 and Reggexp2 since i want to have stored RSTART and RLENGTH values. The desired output hasn't the part of the string which maches with the Regexp.

Comment: `The desired output hasn't the` - I don't understand that sentence. So what if your expected output, because you clearly had written that you want the string between the Regexp1 and Regexp2 - I believe now you state otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Considering that your actual Input_file is same as shown samples, if this is the case could you please try following then(good to have new version of `awk` since old versions may not support number of times logic for regex).

```
awk '
match($0,/\([0-9]+\){5}.*\([0-9]\){4}/){
  print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
}' Input_file
```

In case your number of parenthesis values are not fixed then you could do like as follows:

```
awk '
match($0,/\([0-9]+\){1,}.*\([0-9]\){1,}/){
  print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
}' Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

If this isn't all you need:

```
$ sed 's/Regexp1\(.*\)Regexp2/\1/' file
(1)(2)(3)(4)(5)xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx(20)(21)(22)(23)
```

or using GNU awk for gensub():

```
$ awk '{print gensub(/Regexp1(.*)Regexp2/,"\\1",1)}' file
(1)(2)(3)(4)(5)xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx(20)(21)(22)(23)
```

then edit your question to be far clearer with your requirements and example.